# How to disable swipe to delete option at UITableView

Tags: uitableview, swift4, editing

I have 2 UITableView (Table-1 & Table-2) at same UIViewController. I want to editing functionality in my Table-2.

I have added tableview datasource method in my view controller as mentioned below: -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {

            tableView.beginUpdates()
            myArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
```

and both tableview calling this method. So each tableview cells are able to open delete option.

But I want this delete editing option in only Table-2. I want to restrict delete editing option functionality in Table-1.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function provided by UITableViewDelegate:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Simply implement some logic to check if you want to allow editing at the given `indexPath` and given `tableView` and `return true` if you want editing/deleting and `return false` if you don't.

Hope this helps!